# How to create require.js package using grunt

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs, amd

I've build a js library that I'd like to package as an AMD module using grunt. There are other tasks that concatenate the library file, so I'd have the non-AMD module as a start.

This is how the `Gruntfile` looks like:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    concat: {
      all: {
        options: {
          separator: '\n\n',
          stripBanners: true,
          banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
            '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n\n'
        },
        files: {
          'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js': ['src/file1.js', 'src/file2.js'], // this works
          'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.amd.js': ['src/file1.js', 'src/file2.js'] // this is meant to create the AMD version of the library
        }
      }
    }
 });
 grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);
};
```

The resulting file (for target `library.amd.js`) is meant to contain the content of `library.js` including the `define(..., ..., ...)` part of `require.js`:

```
define('library', ['dependency1', 'dependency2'], function(dep1, dep2) {
  // content of library.js here
});
```

How could I go about doing this? I thought about adding a `header.js` (for `define('library...`) and `footer.js` (for `});`) to the build sources of the AMD target, but was hoping there's a more elegant solution. I also looked at grunt templates, but couldn't find a way of including complete files into a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`grunt-umd`](https://github.com/alexlawrence/grunt-umd) to wrap your files in the Universal Module Definition

Many libraries concat a header and footer file in the build as you describe. An example of this is [snap.svg](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/tree/master/src) (see [amd-banner.js](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/src/amd-banner.js), and [amd-footer.js](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/src/amd-footer.js), and their [gruntfile.js](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L23-L43))

Comment: Thanks for confirming and the example. I'll use that.